# When is SecurityContext cleared in Spring boot applciation? It's being retained even after the api call is complete

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my application, we need to validate the auth token passed in the Authorization header. Both the headers clientName and Authorizaiton are must. If, clientName is not passed we just need to log that "client name is missing in the request". In the Auth configuration we are only applying security on write operations. The problem is - if first time correct clientName and auth token are passed, the next api calls work fine even when both the required headers are missing (Issue observed while making call from swagger / postman. Expected response - 403: Forbidden).

However, when I cUrl it, I get proper forbidden error code. When I debugged it, found that `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` is still returning the last set context.

Do I also need to do `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null)` when the headers are missing?

Below is the sample code:

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(httpRequest.getHeader(clientName)) {
                log.info("missing client information");
            } else {

                final String authorizationHeader = httpRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(clientName) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(authorizationHeader)) {
                    Matcher matcher = BEARER_TOKEN_PATTERN.matcher(authorizationHeader);
                    if (matcher.matches()) {

                        Client client = null;
                        try {
                            client = authService.load(clientName);
                        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                            log.debug("Client not registered");
                        }

                        final String storedToken = !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(client) ? client.getClientSecret() : StringUtils.EMPTY;

                        if (storedToken.equals(matcher.group(2))) {
                            ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication = new ClientAuthentication(client, storedToken, client.getScopes());
                            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(clientAuthentication);
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Here is the AuthConfiguration:

````
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class AuthConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final Boolean isSecurityEnabled;
    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthConfiguration(final MyProps props) {
        isSecurityEnabled = props.getIsSecurityEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.addFilterBefore(new MyCustomAuthenticationFilter(authService), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        if (isSecurityEnabled) {
            http.requestCache()
                    .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
                    .and().csrf().disable().formLogin().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v*/channels/**")
                    .hasAnyAuthority(Scope.CHANNELS_WRITE.getDefaultScope(), Scope.ADMIN.getDefaultScope())
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/v*/channels/**")
                        .hasAnyAuthority(Scope.CHANNELS_WRITE.getDefaultScope(), Scope.ADMIN.getDefaultScope())
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT).authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH).authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).authenticated();
        } else {
            http.csrf().disable().formLogin().disable().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Can you please add WebSecurityConfig detail

Comment: I have added WebSecurityConfig details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be this behavior is generally related to Session Management.

Since you are using token based Security, need to explicitly define Session Management as Stateless in `WebSecurityConfig` something like this

```
http
.sessionManagement()
.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

Refer [this](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) for more detail

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. But I am curious, why it was earlier working fine when I used cURL but not through postman / swagger.